# String to date Conversion in Java

Tags: java

I have this code

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
String sDate="2013-11-13";
String formattedDate=ft.format( ft.parse(sDate));
```

but this not working. Any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the date format like this

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Edit

comment question : but I need dd/mm/yyyy format?

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2013-11-13");
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change SimpleDate Format to below, and it shall work

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Then your date should in 13-11-2013

Comment: @Eman Don't focus on how you want the `Date` format, focus on what format it is in right now.  `Date` has no format, that's what `DateFormatter`s are for...

Comment: @ MadProgrammer:: Thanks alot for telling me this very basic point